# Open source software for Municipality Meeting

Tags: open-source, meetings

I am maintaining some proprietary code (very OLD code: VB6... :-() for Italian Municipality Meetings. I add an image to clarify the kind of meetings:

[image]

I'm not native English, so I am not even sure I'm using the correct terms, so please pardon me...

The software handles speakers prenotations, microphone activation, webcams activation, pan, tilt, zoom, speeches storage on digital media, and more secondary tasks. Every speaker (usually 20 ~ 30 people) has it's own position and microphone. All devices currently receive commands on RS-232 lines (serial interfaces).

Do you know of any modern software solution I could upgrade to?
The optimum should be an open-source, full digital, well supported solution, but any combination of these requisites would go... :-)

Comment: “The software handles speakers prenotations, …” but what does it do exactly? Do you have a command console to e.g. activate the microphone at the third position on the front row, start recording, etc.? What kind of hardware does it run on, and what operating system?

Comment: Yes, the meeting president is able to choose whom to let speak, clicking on it's icon on the screen, and so on... Currently all runs on windows (VB6...), hardware... how does hardware is involved in the question?